# Web Scrape a Website at every visit

Tags: web-scraping

I have a website for my soccer team where I want to put in the standings. The organisation (dbu.dk) has the standings where there is (as I know) no API to subtract the standings to your website. So I thought about using web scrape.

Is there a way that I can, every time a person visits the site (edit: or every day at 8am), web scrape the standings to my own site? I consider using JS if possible.

I don't know anything about web scraping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled over PHP cUrl which does what I want.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: That's strange, if PHP curl solve sthe problem of 'web-scraping' then your initial question is not well described. 

PHP curl can help you fetch the page markup but will not parse the DOM. You'll need a dom parser for that; a useful one in PHP is [Simple HTML Dom](https://github.com/sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser), there is a Node [Node Scraping Tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/scraping-the-web-with-node-js) here as well since you mentioned javascript